# Windows 7 x64 Installation - BSOD with ACPI.SYS

Tags: windows-7

I'm receiving a BSOD on a clean install of Windows 7. The install is booting from a DVD, but when it starts up Windows it dies with a BSOD. I've disabled any "potential" items from the bios and upgraded the bios.

Machine is a Shuttle SX38P2 PRO, Intel Quad Core, 8 gigs of memory, Nvidia 9800 GT

Any ideas on how to get around this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so the solution was resolved by swapping out the DVD. Do not know why it was bad, since it worked fine in another machine.

Answer (score 0):

As found on Technet:

Manually install the Standard PC hardware abstraction layer (HAL):

1. Reboot the computer to restart Setup.
2. When Setup starts again, press F7 when you see the "Press F6 if you need to install a third-party SCSI or RAID driver" screen.

Windows automatically disables the installation of the ACPI HAL and installs the Standard PC HAL. You should also contact the manufacturer of your computer to obtain a BIOS that is fully ACPI compliant.

Comment: I would try that, but it fails before the "Press F6 ..." prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Can you boot in vga mode? if so - try a less capable video card? I had issues after installing Vista on an nVidia machine. After rebuilding it a couple of times, I discovered that it was a known problem, and there was an updated nVidia driver (the 'even more recent' one on windows update was no good)

Comment: I didn't see any options in the bios to boot to VGA mode, and since it is pcix, I don't have any other video cards.

Comment: VGA Boot is triggered by pressing f8 immediately after the BIOS POST. It should give you a menu of safe mode, safe mode with networking, safe mode with command prompt, last known good, logging and VGA mode options.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have more than on CD/DVD drive? Are you installing on the first hard drive, or first parition?

i've seen Windows (XP) BSOD during gui install portion because the drive letters get mangled after first reboot when devices get switched around and it loses where everything is.

Comment: I only have single unformatted HD and the CD/DVD in the machine.

Answer (score 0):

What is the blue-screen error code? There are many reasons for Windows to generate a blue screen, and troubleshooting is easier when you know which one it is.

Given Windows 7 is currently only available as an ISO, is it possible that you have a bad burn? I had a problem with Virtual PC on Windows 2000 several years ago, where it would crash if the VPC network services driver was enabled. Windows XP on another computer would simply not be able to use the network. I discovered that the driver was actually bad on the disc, the checksum not matching.

Comment: I verified the burn and it appears correct. I'll try a new one just in case the verifcation is wrong.